# bind method from Bluebird saves context(this) between calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

After this docs http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html I expect 
that life of binded context will ends with end of call. But apparently it is not.
Following code:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const chain = (callNumber) => {
    console.log('call:', callNumber, '============');
    return asyncFunction()
        .bind({})
        .then(() => {
            console.log('this', callNumber, this);
            this.t = 1
        })
        .then(() => {
            this.t2 = 2
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('this', callNumber, this);
        })
};

const asyncFunction = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    return Promise.delay(100)
        .then(resolve);
});

chain(1).then(() => chain(2));
```

produces this result:

```
call: 1 ============
this 1 {}
this 1 { t: 1, t2: 2 }
call: 2 ============
this 2 { t: 1, t2: 2 }
this 2 { t: 1, t2: 2 }
```

Expected result:

```
call: 1 ============
this 1 {}
this 1 { t: 1, t2: 2 }
call: 2 ============
this 2 {}
this 2 { t: 1, t2: 2 }
```

Is this correct behaviour or I made mistake somewhere?

Comment: Please add result as you except or want

Comment: .bind doesn't work with arrow functions - they have lexical this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluebird `Promise.bind` is misused. It's supposed to be used with dynamic `this`:

> Without arrow functions that provide lexical this, the correspondence between async and sync code breaks down when writing object-oriented code. .bind alleviates this.

E.g.:

```
promise.bind({})
.then(function () {
    console.log('this', callNumber, this);
    this.t = 1
})
```

With arrow functions, `this` is lexical and refers to Node module, `module.exports`. It stays the same between `chain` calls.